# How to create a privateKey/publicKey pair of KeyObject return type and 256 bits length in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, jwt, cryptojs, jose

How to create a privateKey/publicKey pair of KeyObject return type and 256 bits length in Node.js?
Kindly ask you to provide a working example.
I tried this one:

```
const { generateKeyPair } = require('node:crypto');
generateKeyPair(
    'rsa',
    {
      modulusLength: 1024,
      publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem'
      },
      privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs8',
        format: 'pem',
        cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
        passphrase: secret
      }
    },
    (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
      if (err) res.end(JSON.stringify(err));

      console.log('private: ', privateKey);
      console.log('public: ', publicKey);
    }
  );
```

But when I change **modulusLength** value to the required 256 bits I get an error.
I need it for JOSE JWE secret.

Comment: *I get an error.* - Then please let us know which error it is.

Comment: Error: error:1C8000AB:Provider routines::key size too small

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't actually want a 256 bit RSA key. You need a 256 bit symmetric secret based on the other questions you've opened. You also don't need a KeyObject, a Uint8Array / Buffer will do fine for the jose library you're attempting to use ([docs](https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/210)).

Anyway. You can generate a random KeyObject (of type "secret") like so.

```js
const crypto = require('node:crypto')

// option 1
crypto.generateKey('aes', { length: 256 }, (err, secret) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle err
  } else {
    console.log(secret)
  }
})


// option 2
crypto.createSecretKey(crypto.randomBytes(32))
```

`crypto.createSecretKey` is also how you would re-instantiate a secret KeyObject based on random bytes you have elsewhere stored and serialized.

Comment: The fact is, I want to sign a JWE using a private key, Then I want to send a public key to the Client to be able to decrypt that JWE on the Client side and read the data of the JWE.
For that, I need a private/public key pair.

Also, I need a way to generate those keys pare based on the secret string I have in .env file on my backend side.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not how JWE works, neither is there a way to take a secret string and turning it to a keypair.